# Why isn't mysqldump recognizing the user with -u option?

Tags: mysql

I want to dump a database using the user `root`, but the command:

```
$ mysqldump –u root -p databaseName > file.sql
```

After entering the root password generates:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'userX'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Where `userX` is the local user in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). It seems it's not recognizing the -u option.

But `$ mysql -u root -p` works as `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` returns:

```
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

What's happening with mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a mysqldump problem. I wrote the command from the beginning and it worked.

It seems it was a ssh / console problem showing maybe a broken command.

I keep this answer if anyone else got this problem because of this issue.